# How to find out the width of a tkinter window without an update?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to center a tkinter window on the screen, which can be done with:

```
root.geometry(f"+{(root.winfo_screenwidth()-root.winfo_width())//2}+"
              f"{(root.winfo_screenheight()-root.winfo_height())//2}")
```

This is using the screen width and the width of the window to calculate the upper left corner. However, in order to find out the window width, I have to run `root.update()` as shown in the following example, which leads to the window showing up at a wrong position for a tiny moment.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
for i in range(20):
    tk.Label(root, text='Hello World! '*5).pack()

# without the following line, the window dimensions are not being calculated
root.update()

root.geometry(f"+{(root.winfo_screenwidth()-root.winfo_width())//2}"
              f"+{(root.winfo_screenheight()-root.winfo_height())//2}")

root.mainloop()
```

To avoid this, I can think of two solutions:

- defining the window size in pixels, which means that the window size does not adjust automatically anymore, and
- doing something like `root.update()` without the window being visible.

Comment: What's the `file_picker`?

Comment: Oh, I didn't change it from its original context. I refer to the window (```root```).

Comment: Sounds interesting,like you said,"With the start of the mainloop, the window is showing up on the default position".From this point,"calculating the position needs some time".Especially on slow hardware.So I think it is impossible to do this without some time.But do you really think user can see it in 10ms?

Comment: I don't know whether it is really 10 ms, but I can definitly see it on my older laptop. It is just like flashing, not that I could see the content of the window or something. The goal would be not to take less time, but rather to hide the window during the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to avoid the call to `update()`, but you could initially make the window completely transparent, which would prevent it from even momentarily showing up in the wrong position — thereby granting you the opportunity to position it properly and manually making it visible.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

# This changes the alpha value (how transparent the window should be).
# It ranges from 0.0 (completely transparent) to 1.0 (completely opaque).
root.attributes("-alpha", 0.0)

for i in range(20):
    tk.Label(root, text='Hello World! '*5).pack()

tk.Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).pack()

root.update()  # Allow the window's size to be calculated,

# Move it so it's centered on the screen.
root.geometry(f"+{(root.winfo_screenwidth()-root.winfo_width())//2}"
              f"+{(root.winfo_screenheight()-root.winfo_height())//2}")

# Now make it visible.
root.attributes("-alpha", 1.0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I just updated the original question with an example. Your code centers the upper left corner of the window, which is better to be seen with more content (as in the added example).

Comment: OK — I've updated my original answer accordingly.

Comment: The attribute ```-alpha``` behaves differently on linux: I had to add ```root.wait_visibility()``` before setting the alpha value to 0 and ```time.sleep(0.2)``` (after importing ```time```) before calling ```root.update()```. It's not the cleanest solution, but seems to work.

Comment: You might not need the `wait_visibility` and the delay if you used `update_idletasks()` instead of `update()`.

Comment: To me, the usage of ```update_idletasks()``` seemed to have no effect on this, I still need both lines.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve a clean window display is shown in the following code.

`withdraw` the master immediately, create widgets, `update` master before centering window and finally `deiconify`.

Works every time.

```py
import tkinter as tk

def screencenter(o):
    w, h = o.winfo_width(), o.winfo_height()
    x = int((o.winfo_screenwidth() - w) / 2)
    y = int((o.winfo_screenheight() - h) / 2)
    o.geometry(f'{w}x{h}+{x}+{y}')

master = tk.Tk()
master.withdraw()

# create whatever widgets you need

master.update()
screencenter(master)
master.deiconify()
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does not work for me (Linux). The window dimensions fetched in ```screencenter()``` are 1x1, suggesting that the contents have not yet been processed at that point.

Comment: Try changing update to update_idletasks. I'd be interested to know it that works. @Jakob Schödl

Comment: @Darek ```update_idletasks``` seems to make no difference in that case.

Comment: @Jakob Schödl it was worth a try. One alternative is to modify screencenter to screencenter( o, w, h ) then remove `o.winfo_width and height` and pass desired width and height.

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is `root.withdraw()` and `root.deiconify()`.

The former will hide your window from view and the latter will show it.

I've included a full example below.

```
from tkinter import Tk

def show_it():
    height = root.winfo_height()
    width = root.winfo_width()

    root.geometry(f"+{(s_width - width)//2}+"
              f"{(s_height - height)//2}")
    # show it again
    root.deiconify()

root = Tk()

s_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
s_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()

root.withdraw()

# hide the window
root.after(200, show_it)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should execute `root.deiconify()` after `root.geometry(...)`.

Comment: Fixed. For some reason I was under the impression screen updates wouldn't take place in the loop until after the callback had completely run.

Comment: This is also unable to find out the window size. The hidden window appears to have a size of 1x1, which lets tkinter display its upper left corner in the center of the screen.

Comment: Try to adjust the delay of `after()`.